# com.liferay.portal.kernel.scripting.ScriptingException: startup > failed:_Script1.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class > org.apache.commons.httpclient

Tags: groovy, liferay

I'm trying to customize a kaleo xml workflow in liferay Portal 7.4 in order to send sms notifications after submitting a form (form in web & content in liferay).

I added a script with groovy integrating Twilio api to do this but after submitting the form i'm getting this error:

> com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogSanitizerException:
> com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.action.executor.ActionExecutorException:
> com.liferay.portal.kernel.scripting.ScriptingException: startup
> failed:*Script1.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod* @ line 12, column
> 25._                           import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;_
> ^**Script1.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration* @ line 5, column 25.*
> import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration;_
> ^**Script1.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient* @ line 7, column 25.*
> import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;_
> ^**Script1.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials* @ line 3, column 10.*
> import org.apache.commons....   at com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.scripting.internal.action.ScriptActionExecutor.execute(ScriptActionExecutor.java:59)
> ~[?:?]    at
> com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.internal.action.executor.ActionExecutorManagerImpl.executeKaleoAction(ActionExecutorManagerImpl.java:60)
> ~[?:?]    at
> com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.internal.action.KaleoActionExecutorImpl.executeKaleoActions(KaleoActionExecutorImpl.java:61)
> ~[?:?]    at
> com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.node.BaseNodeExecutor.enter(BaseNodeExecutor.java:51)
> ~[?:?]    at
> com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.internal.graph.DefaultGraphWalker.follow(DefaultGraphWalker.java:70)
> ~[?:?]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ~[?:1.8.0_332]    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[?:1.8.0_332]    at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[?:1.8.0_332]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[?:1.8.0_332]

And this is my groovy script :

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair


String twilioHost = 'api.twilio.com'

String apiID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

String aipPass = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'

HostConfiguration hc = new HostConfiguration()

hc.setHost(twilioHost, 443, "https")

def url = "/2008-08-01/Accounts/$apiID/SMS/Messages"

def client = new HttpClient()

Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(apiID, aipPass)

client.getState().setCredentials(null, null, defaultcreds)

PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);

post.addParameter 'IfMachine', 'Continue'

post.addParameter 'Method', 'POST'

post.addParameter 'From', '[YourNumber]'

post.addParameter 'To', parameters.phoneNumber

post.addParameter 'Body', 'This is an SMS from Axeda'

client.executeMethod(hc, post);

post.releaseConnection();
```

Do you have please an idea how to resolve this issue and where to add the dependencies jars since adding it in liferay-plugin-package.properties is depracated for liferay 7 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know how to call third-party dependencies on this groovy script but what I would do in your case is create an OSGI service that does all this for you. So you would only have to call this service on your groovy script.